# Arm64 is not showing in Unity 5.6.6 32bit

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, arm64

I made a game and tried to upload in google play store but it said to set my native code to 64 bit android. I searched for the solution in which I found out to check **ARM64** in player setting but I couldn't find that check button. Could anyone help me..?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [unity blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/):

> The move to a 64-bit Android world is imminent, and we at Unity
>   believe that it’s a good thing! We added support for Android 64-bit
>   with Unity 2018.2, and we have now backported it to Unity 2017.4. Read
>   on to get more details on Google’s  64-bit requirement, ARM 64-bit
>   advantages, and Android App Bundle support in Unity.

Comment: Thanks!!  I have another query also that can I download unity 2018.2 in windows 7 32 bit and can I upgrade my prject to 2018.2 or I have to do all these stuff buying a new laptop.?

Comment: @ElectronicVisionStudio Unfortunately, the latest versions of unity support only 64-bit architecture.